# What to do after receiving 1099?

Tags: united-states, form-1099

I know I need to report that income, but I'll already be doing so after downloading and summarizing my transactions via my bank.

Do I need to separately report income from each 1099?

Do I need to attach the 1099 form?

Comment: Different _types_ of 1099's are reported differently, e.g. -INT and -OID as interest, -DIV mostly as dividends but sometimes other things, -B -S usually as capital gain/loss, -R as pensions-etc, -SA -QA as their specialized types if not excluded, -NEC -K usually as business (C or F), -G -MSC all over the place. If you have more than one distinct SE business you should report _those_ separately, which may or may not correspond to different 1099's. Beware txns near end of year -- some may actually get into your bank account in the new year but be taxable in the old year.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 [Please post this as an answer, not a comment.](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/10997)

Answer (score 1):

Your bank information would contain multiple transactions, and they do not necessarily need to be separately entered in the tax return. They can be aggregated. The 1099 will simply help the IRS to validate your information from the bank

When you have income reported on multiple 1099 forms, all you should do is aggregate the income amounts from your 1099 forms and report the total on the relevant sections of your tax return.

You do not need to attach the actual 1099 forms to your tax return when you file it.

Comment: Ok so, as a freelance writer, I work with many clients, say clients A, B, and C, who gives a 1099. Client D does not give a 1099. So should I report just one number - the sum of money I received from all 4 clients, or separate it into sum of ABC and the amount of money I got from D?

Answer (score 0):

No, 1099s are informational returns. They're used by the IRS to cross reference your tax return and confirm that you've reported all your income correctly.

Comment: Nit: IF a 1099 shows withholding (which is common only on -R and sometimes -G) AND you paper-file, do attach it.